# Empty result set from MSSQL query on Ubuntu

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `sqlsrv` module on my Ubuntu 18.04 with `PHP 7.2` to run the following sql query

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(CardNo, '0', ' ')),' ', '0') AS staff_id,
    FORMAT(PunchDatetime, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as 'date',
    FORMAT(min(PunchDatetime), 'HH:mm:ss') AS time_in,
    IIF(min(PunchDatetime) != max(PunchDatetime), FORMAT(max(PunchDatetime), 'HH:mm:ss'), NULL) AS time_out
    FROM PunchRecords
    WHERE cast('2018-11-01' as date) = cast(FORMAT(PunchDatetime, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date)
    group by CardNo, FORMAT(PunchDatetime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    order by CardNo";
```

The same query executed on Windows returns data from the table, but returns empty result set when run in Ubuntu environment.

Any feedback on the issue will be appreciated.

Comment: And if you simply do `select count(*) from PunchRecords`?

Comment: Try `WHERE cast('2018-11-01' as date) = cast(PunchDatetime as date)` instead

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious reason could be the different date format on the Ubuntu. '2018-11-01' can be interpreted either as YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-DD-MM. Just check this:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT CAST('2014-09-13' AS DATETIME);
GO
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT CAST('2014-09-13' AS DATETIME);--ERROR: there's no month "13"
GO
```

When comparing dates, just compare the date - do not convert it to string. Simply use:

```
WHERE '20181101' = cast(PunchDatetime as date)
```

Comment: Comparing the strings didn't work. Casting did work.